# Is there anything online like the old "calca"?

Tags: symbolic-computation

[Calca](http://calca.io/) was a tool for Windows/Mac where you could type formulas with markdown text interspersed, like:

```
# My work
a=7
b=2+a^2
b=> 51
```

Where it would dynamically show you the results after `=>` and recalculate everything when you change anything. I think it's been abandoned some years ago.

Is there anything like that available as an online tool? Seems like a nice mashup of a spreadsheet (because it recalculates as you go), a text editor with Markup, and a symbolic math package (though Calca didn't have much symbolic math, just basic equation solving). It would be great to have something simple like this.

Comment: I use Jupyter Notebook. It's not exactly the same, but I like it a lot.

Comment: Does a Jupyter notebook recalculate if you change older values though?